# Automate variable values during compilation

Tags: node.js, jenkins, reactjs, automation, recaptcha

I am working on a big team (around 15) for a web application that use Google captcha. As you might know, is necessary a public and a secret key that are associated to a URL.

We have multiple environments where we test our work. Therefore, for have a valid captcha, we need multiple google keys for our captcha.

The problem is when we commit our work, many of us modify this keys and when we deploy it, captcha not works because we have put an invalid value.

I am looking a way to automate this and  solve this problem. I have think two ways:

- Put them as global variable when we start our nodeJS app, but is a very big string to remember it, so is easy to fail when we write them.
- Automate it with Jenkins, bubt I am not sure if is a good practice to add it in this step (I think to make a shell script that replace the value for a value in the code -i.e. CAPTCHA_KEY-).

I don't like any of these ideas, so I am open to hear new options

Comment: You could leverage environment variables: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#be-environmentally-aware Short version: use a NOT versioned file to store the key/url/whatever config and make your code load this config file. Every dev will have their own file and the code will be common and untouched.

Answer (score 2):

**Add the keys using environment variables on your machine.**

A good example of this can be found in this link: [Storing Keys](http://pmuellr.blogspot.com/2014/09/keeping-secrets-secret.html)

This is also good practice because you should not be committing and pushing the keys to the repo.  It is best to add any file with private information to .gitignore so that these keys are not stored with the project.  If the project were ever compromised, whoever obtains the code would not have the keys because they would not be stored in the repo.

Comment: That is a good option!! We can't use .gitignore in that file because we use another variables (not keys, just "global" variables) that are important. I really like you answer @Mike! And very easy too :)

Comment: Glad you think this will work for you!  Also, you should definitely try and get those keys into a file that does not get checked into the repo.  If you want them to still be in the project (and not in environment variables), put them in a separate config file that does not include anything else so that you can .gitignore that config file.